# Automate Password Removal in directory with password in excel with script

Tags: python, java, excel, automation, power-automate

Essentially I receive a bunch of files every so often, the files are excel documents that are password protected ( the password is the same for all and static). I want the script to iterate through each file within the directory and remove the password protection feature you apply locally within Excel settings.

I have tried using the following python script but get consistent errors
I have also tried looking into using power automate though it does not have the functionality required.

```
enter code here import os import win32com.client as win32
 input_directory = (r'C:direcotry\path\etc') 
output_directory = (r'C:\Users\Downloads') 
password = 'password' 
try: excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False  

for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        input_file_path = os.path.join(input_directory, filename)
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, filename)
        
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_file_path, False, True, None, password)
        
        workbook.SaveAs(output_file_path, None, '', '', '', '', 0, None, False)
        workbook.Close(False)
        
excel.Quit()
except Exception as e: print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

Comment: Format the code properly.

Comment: You can use msoffcrypto  or even just Xlwings instead of win32com

Comment: Have you tried this and do you have a working script for operation?

Comment: Managed to get it this working 

import msoffcrypto
import io
import pandas as pd

decrypted = io.BytesIO()

with open(r"C:\DIRECTORY\NAME\AND\THEN\FILE\NAME.xlsx", "rb") as f:
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)
    file.load_key(password="Password")  # Use password
    file.decrypt(decrypted)

df = pd.read_excel(decrypted)
print(df)